# Start Windows Command Prompt in Certain Directory

Tags: windows, shell, directory, command, command-line-interface

I am usually working within the same directory (or subfolders of it) and it has quite a long path so it would be really convenient if my command prompt automatically started in that directory (instead of `C:\Users\username`). How can I change the starting folder to the one I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to do it:

1. Create a shortcut that opens CMD in the directory you want (recommended).

- Create a Command Prompt shortcut
- Access the properties of the shortcut and set the path where you want it to open in the "Start in" field

2. Change the path that the command prompt uses by default

- Open regedit
- Go to "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
- Create a new "String Value" with the name "Autorun" and with the value "cd /d C:\EXAMPLEDIR"

Comment: first method didn't work as my properties didn't have a 'start in' field, but the second method works perfectly, thank you!